# Problem with execute a procedure in SSIS with execute SQL task

Tags: visual-studio, stored-procedures, ssis, execute-sql-task

I write in three variables values from a DataBase using an Execute SQL task and if I check if values was correctly written with the breakpoint, everything seems to be correct.
Now I want use the variables that were written before in an other execute SQL task to execute a procedure. The problem is that the value of the variables aren't correctly mapped (I think).
I thought that the variables aren't global (in fact when I check for the variables the values are always zero while during the debug in the task in which I write the variables aren't zero). 
How can I solve this issue?

This is how I call the procedure:

```
exec FillCalendar ?, ?, ?, ?
```

(I have 4 variables).

This is the parameter mapping:

[image]

They are in the order of question marks in the query.
They are all of INT type.

Comment: Are your parameters mapped correctly? Can you share the screenshot of your parameter Mapping window in Execute SQL Task?

Comment: @FaisalMehboob I shared it.

Comment: Can you show us how those variables are getting set in the upstream `Execute SQL Task`? Is any of this business logic inside a loop? Is any of the business logic split between being inside a loop and outside a loop?

Comment: When I put a breakpoing in the sql task that will do the procedure, they are correctly set. What you want to see? The way in which I stored the variables from the DataBase or the general settings of the sql task in which there is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into problems before where SSIS doesn't recognize the input parameters correctly in the `Execute SQL Task`.

My "best practice" is to now declare placeholder variables for all input parameters, and then work with the placeholders. For example, I might change your stored proc call to this:

```
DECLARE @Param1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Param2 INT
DECLARE @Param3 BIT
DECLARE @Param4 DATE

SET @Param1 = ?
SET @Param2 = ?
SET @Param3 = ?
SET @Param4 = ?

EXEC FillCalendar @ProcInput1 = @Param1, @ProcInput2 = @Param2, @ProcInput3 = @Param3, @ProcInput4 = @Param4
```

Where `@ProcInput1, @ProcInput2, @ProcInput3, and @ProcInput4` are the stored proc's input parameter names. Obviously you'd declare your placeholders with the correct data type.

**Additional Information**

You can refer to the following links for more information about passing variables from and into SSIS tasks.

- [Passing Variables to and from an SSIS task](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/)
- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)

Comment: Same problem as before. The SQL task goes on but the procedure didn't do anything.

Comment: I think it's a problem of variables because are written in a previously SQL task and I think after are lost.

Comment: @MrCaptainAlex i added two links to digital's answer, check them in order to now if you are reading variables correctly

Comment: I followed exactly the guide of the second link. I can't understand what the problem is. I load the values from a table in the database through a sql task and with another sql task I execute the procedure. I don't understand what the mistake could be.